# PHP. Handle every url on website

Tags: php, joomla

I want every user request(url) to handle in index.php (or some another file). I need to handle these requests to check if requested page exists(in database) and then construct the page . Using this approach I can store content not in the server itself, but in the database. I suspect that Joomla cms works this way. I am right? Can you post sample code?

(user must see full url he typed in browser's adress bar, and when he click on the backward arrow in browser, he must get the previous page - I suppose i can't use redirect and multiple requests)

Comment: I've got a pretty big NMP field for rent!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?params=$1 [NC]
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a design pattern for it called [Front Controller Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern), which provides a centralised entry point.

To achieve this in PHP, you may use any MVC framework like Codeignitor which works in FCP by default.

To achieve this in PHP, first have your .htaccess modified.

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

And in your index.php, have a logic like this:

**index.php** (code simplified for understanding)

```
    <?php

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/about') {
        // Logic for printing About
        getContent('about');
    } elseif ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/products') {
        getContent('products');
    } else {
        // Logic for printing 404 page
    }



    function getContent($key) {

        // load value based on $key 

        //print content. 
    }
```